# Visual Build professional compile errors?

Tags: c++, visual-build-professional

I am using visual build professional and one of the steps is a 'Make VS 2003' (c++ project). However, every time I get the following error:

fatal error C1033: cannot open program database ''

If I compile the project myself in visual studios it works fine.

Anyone know why this would be, or how I can fix it?

Comment: Post here: http://www.kinook.com/Forum/

Comment: @nobugz: huh? (15 chars)

Comment: It is the support forum for the company that sells Visual Build Pro.  Best place to find out why the tool is passing bad command line options to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I have gotten that error in the past when I have an old .pdb file (or one that was somehow corrupted).  If so, the error message should indicate which file it is.  You should be able to manually delete that file. I think it has often been `vc60.pdb`.

There is also some information about this error [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks5fw35.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have cleaned up the projects (removed all pdb's) but I am still getting this error.

Comment: @Zenox:  What is the command you are using to fire off the build?  Also, is there more information included in the error message?

Comment: The command line option that gets generated for this is:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" D:\project.vcproj /build "Release DLL" /project D:\project.vcproj

If I run this from the command-line it compiles successfully!

There is no more detail in the error log. I am going to also post on the kinook forum and see if they have any suggestions.

Comment: @Zenox:  Are you sure that is the correct path to devenv?  The path indicates it is VS2003.  In your post, you said it was VS2008.  I would think the error would be different in that case.  The other thing you might look at is the output path for the build.  If it is different than the normal "release" directory under the project, maybe it has an old .pdb file?

Comment: Sorry, my original post should have said 2003 (legacy project not updated to 2008 yet). The path is correct (I can compile this from the command line and it works :S). I will check the output and manually clean all of the PDB's and see if this improves anything. Thanks!